# How to get simple syntax barplot?

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

I have a dataframe df, and I want to barplot it, but my barplot code quite long and alot of hand coppy, anyone can help me get better?
Thank you for reading my question ^^!

[My dataframes and my barplot code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRuKC.jpg)

[My expected barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFqsd.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = df.plot.bar(x='label_1', y=['value_20', 'value_22'], xlabel='')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

[Minimal Working Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
data = {'label_1': ['DAV_AddLife', 'DAV_AddSlot'],
        'value_20': [10, 12],
        'label_2': ['DAV_AddLife', 'DAV_AddSlot'],
        'value_22': [13, 14]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# Output
       label_1  value_20      label_2  value_22
0  DAV_AddLife        10  DAV_AddLife        13
1  DAV_AddSlot        12  DAV_AddSlot        14
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X_points = np.arange(len(df["label_1"]))    # points on X-axis that divide the blue plots from orange plots 
bar_width = 0.4                             # width of each bar plot

# Plot for 'value_20' (BLUE PLOTS):
plt.bar(
    x = X_points - bar_width/2,             # points at which bar plot is centered at
    height = df["value_20"],
    width = bar_width,
    label = "value_20",
    color = "blue"
)

# Plot for 'value_22' (ORANGE PLOTS):
plt.bar(
    x = X_points + bar_width/2,             # points at which bar plot is centered at
    height = df["value_22"],
    width = bar_width,-
    label = "value_22",
    color = "orange"
)
plt.xticks(X_points, df["label_1"])         # converting label in the X axis
plt.legend()                                # displaying the plot legend (top-right corner)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).